# How to make a TCP server using tomcat (and spring)

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tcp

I was thinking on something and I wondered if it already exists.

I would like to have a WAR to deploy on a tomcat which could be able to handle TCP requests from clients, sending data via TCP, etc. I need more functionality than a basic standalone TCP server like handling sessions for living connections, interceptors (security, compression, etc.) on inbound requests, tomcat managed connection thread pool, eventually routing of TCP message with a specific format.

I would expect something very similar to a http server but with the ability to access all alive connections and send messages (which is IMO the main functionality of TCP vs HTTP)

I have found some articles about opening an TCP servlet on tomcat but as said previously, I need more than just open a socket. Since I would like something very similar to HTTP maybe it already exists.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: what you have done so far? "I would like to see what you have done in form of coding"

Comment: Well, I have not done any code since I'm looking for a framework to make it instead of me (hopefully better).